# I want to turn a slash command in Slack into an interactive button

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I have a Slack channel created with a Slack app. In the channel, I can enter /leave and I leave the channel, but I want to have an interactive button in my app that will do the same thing as /leave so a user just needs to click the button instead of entering the command. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Franky, I don't think your idea would work very well, because there is no way to permanently place a button in a Slack channel. So the user will always need to first enter a slash command to get the button. So it would be easier to user `/leave` in the first place.

Comment: We're using the Slack API to programmatically create channels for users in an app.  https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.create

Comment: I understand. But that does not change the fact that you can not create permanent buttons for a channel. Buttons are always part of a message, and messages posted to a channel will disappear from view once more messages are posted.

Comment: Yes, that's true @ErikKalkoken  I meant a button in a message that will initiate the command /leave

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can implement a button on Slack that will allows a user to leave his/her current channel:

- Add an [interactive button](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons) to a message and send it to the channel. e.g. as response to a slash command.
- Once a user clicks the button it will send are request to your app containing its user ID and channel ID
- You app can then use [`conversations.kick`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.kick) to remove the user from the channel, assuming your app has the correct scopes (e.g. `channels.write` for public channels). Note that you need to use the access token for this method. A bot token won't work.

However, there are some potential stumbling blocks to consider:

- The admins of a Slack workspace can restrict the right to kick somebody from a channel. You app will get the corresponding error message if that happens: `restricted_action`. Similar for the "general" channel: `cant_kick_from_general`
- This approach also works in private channel, but with one caveats: Your app needs to be a member of a private channel in order to be able to kick a user from it. Which means that the user that installed your app needs to be a member.

Comment: Oh great! Thank you!